# MVC3 Route/redirect problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

My application is multilingual and I wrote the following route in order to handle the languages:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
               language = "pt", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new { language = @"(pt)|(es)|(en)" }
        );
```

This works for `domain.com` and `domain.com/pt/home/index`. However, if I type `domain.com/home/index` it fails *(404)*.

The desired behavior would be it being redirected to `domain.com/pt/home/index` (pt is the default language).

Whats the best way to achieve this? I've been reading a lot about routes and ActionFilters but nothing seems quite right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would suggest using custom route handler like following

```
public class LanguageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            IRouteHandler handler = new MvcRouteHandler();
            var vals = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
            if(vals["language"] == null)
            {
                vals["language"] = "pt";

            }
            return handler.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
        }
    }
```

and have another route without language route value and set its route handler (global.asax)

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default2", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        ).RouteHandler = new LanguageRouteHandler();
```

This will not redirect Home/index to pt/home/index yet it will provide language = "pt" to your index action method (and all others). if you want to redirect you can implement an actionfilter but redirecting will create problems with post requests. For example when you post a form to /home/index and suppose it is redirected by action filter, the redirected request will lose posted form data

Comment: +1 @Muhammad Adeel Zahid - I did something similar except overriding GetControllerInstance. It's working so far, without auto-redirecting. I'm not sure what is the best implementation, I'll give a try to yours later.

Answer (score 1):

You need two routes, the other one without the language, or add the language parameter at the end

Comment: But how? I can have another route without the language but how do I change the url to one with language? like, if I type domain.com it directs me to domain.com/pt/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
        new { language = @"(pt)|(es)|(en)" }
);
```

and modify your action in this way

```
public ActionResult Index([DefaultValue("pt")] string language)
{
    ...
}
```